# Android - Could not find *.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

After I included the OpenCV library on my Android project, I can't transfer my built apk to the android device anymore. Just getting an error: Could not find *.apk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you defined your project as a library. Try the following steps:

Project -> Properties -> Android -> Uncheck "Is Library" checkbox